# Installing specific version of package

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nuget

I'm new to nuget and this is probably a very simple question but I could not find an answer to it.

I want to install the newest package of **Fluent NHibernate** ([here](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FluentNHibernate/1.3.0.717)) but whenever I install this package it installs the "recommended version" [here](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FluentNHibernate) (the one with the little blue and white thumbs up beside it)

#### Is there a way to specify which version you want to install from the visual studio plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use powershell to get a specific version

```
Install-Package Elmah -Version 1.0
```

See the reference - http://docs.nuget.org/

Comment: So I'm guessing there isn't a way to do this from the ui then eh.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. Sorry! Would be a very nice feature though.

Comment: There's no way to do this from the UI

Comment: +1 The tab completion works really well so it's not that big of a deal.  Thanks Chris.